# Understanding Vector synchrnoization policy

Tags: java, multithreading, vector

I'm reading B. Goetz Java Concurrency In Practice and now I'm at the section adding functionality to existing thread-safe classes. He stated:

> The synchronization policy of Vector is fixed by its specification, so
>   BetterVector would not suffer from this problem.

```
@ThreadSafe
public class BetterVector<E> exends Vector<E>{
    public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(E x){
        boolean absent = !contains(x);
        if(absent)
            add(x);
        return absent;
    }
}
```

So, I tried to figure out myself about synchronization policy of [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) and could only find that

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized.

Does it mean that it synchronized by this object? Or it may mean synchronization by any (probably private) object. If so, `BetterVector<E>` is extremely fragile because it depends on the current implementation of the synchronization policy that is no even specified clearly.

Comment: Looks like you're right. The spec is vague, and in its source methods declared with the `synchronized` keyword (meaning synchronization on `this`), but it is omitted in the Javadoc declarations. Maybe it wasn't always like that?

Comment: I think it's a shame that `Vector` is even mentioned anymore. People mistakenly believe that it's still relevant, when it's been obsolete for almost 20 years. Of course books are books, and it can make for a semi-decent example. I'd still prefer if people pretended the whole class doesn't exist. Too many questions on SO still have `Vector` in them, making me question where these people get their tutorials.

Comment: @Kayaman I myself don't use Vector, but since it was metioned in the book I guessed that it was useful for some purposes...

Comment: It's not. It was designed along with `Hashtable` before the unified `Collections API` in 1.2. But due to backwards compatibility, they will haunt the `java.util` package forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very good question. You are right that the way `Vector` is synchronized does not seem to be specified. (At least, I could find no specification).

However, the current implementation synchronizes on the object itself, and not on an internal object. While this implementation could change at any time, it is unlikely to happen. Too much code probably relies on the current implementation. A change might break all kind of things. I doubt that the code maintainers will take that risk.

My guess is, that code relying on the current implementation is theoretically extremely fragile, in practice there is little risk due to the rather conservative code maintenance and public oversight of the Java development process.

Comment: I doubt that maintainers ever touch `Vector` at all. It is considered obsolete after all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your term "synchronization policy" here. The definition of `synchronized` keyword can be found in Java language spec at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html.

> A synchronized method (§8.4.3.6) automatically performs a lock action when it is invoked; its body is not executed until the lock action has successfully completed. If the method is an instance method, it locks the monitor associated with the instance for which it was invoked (that is, the object that will be known as this during execution of the body of the method). If the method is static, it locks the monitor associated with the Class object that represents the class in which the method is defined. If execution of the method's body is ever completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is automatically performed on that same monitor.

How the locking is translated into OS level call is up to the JVM implementation. However, since the behavior of such keyword has to be defined as above in the Java Language Spec (otherwise this JVM isn't following Java standard), it's guaranteed that the Java programmer writing such statement would achieve the result he wants i.e. such method is thread safe upon using `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: The thing is that the spec doesn't even mention the `synchronized` keyword anywhere, even though it is actually in the JDK sources (but that's just one implementation, not the spec).

Comment: @SergeyTachenov What I pasted is the Java Langeuage Spec not the JVM implementation. Any JVM must follow the JLS. And then "A synchronized method" is what the poster got when he uses `synchronized` keyword on method definition. Thus I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Wait a minute. We are talking about methods `contains` and `add` here. And if they use a different synchronization policy than our `putIfAbsent`, then things go terribly wrong. And its their policy that is not clear from the spec, not our method's.

Comment: Please illustrate how it can be wrong when you have `synchronized` on `putIfAbsent()`. Java object lock is re-entrant so unless the `contains()` and `add()` cannot be called in sequence, which sounds a major pitfall for anyone writing such interface methods.

Comment: You call `contains`. It returns `false`. Someone inserts that very element. They can do it if `add` does _not_ use the `synchronized` keyword (and the spec doesn't say it does), but uses some sort of internal lock instead. Then you happily add another such element after their `add` returns. You end up with duplicate elements, even though your method is called `putIfAbsent`. On the other hand, they could call `add` right after your method returns anyway. But the point is that your method isn't atomic any more.

Comment: Oh, in that sense. Then yes it's dependent on the fact current `Vector` is `synchronized`. I am a bit slow to get you here :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99772/discussion-between-sergey-tachenov-and-alex-suo).